# why does method_defined? still give me false?

Tags: ruby

```
o = Object.new

class << o
  public :puts
end
o.puts "1. #{o.class.method_defined? :puts}"              => false
o.puts "2. #{o.class.method_defined? :public_methods}     => true
```

method_defined? still give me false? even if I declare puts as public, why?

Comment: Not sure why, but testing for `respond_to?` on the instance directly should work ...

Comment: Thanks, Baldrick. o.respond_to? is ok for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
o.class
=> Object

Object.method_defined? :puts
=> false

o.singleton_class
=> #<Class:#<Object:0x2b23858>>

o.singleton_class.method_defined? :puts
=> true
```

I think the code above shows very clear explanation. If you modify the object itself, you should use `singleton_class` to access rather than `class` because the original class does not contain the singleton methods you added.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs for `method_defined?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-method_defined-3F) explain:

> Returns true if the named method is defined by mod (or its included modules and, if mod is a class, its ancestors)

And [the `public` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-public) only sets accessibility; it doesn't move the method definition to the object's context.